# Updating a table of contents in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a current Table of Contents that looks like so:

```
1   Intro
   1.1 Title
   1.2 Title
   1.3 Title
```

I want:

```
1   Overview
   1.1 Intro
      1.1.1 Title
      1.1.2 Title
      1.1.3 Title
```

How do I edit this? I want to make everything I currently have as a sub under Overview.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Overview heading first, then go to the outline view and select everything below the Overview heading and use the demote function.